# SQL Query Last Three Full Months (Excluding Current Month)

Tags: sql, powerbi

I have a database with millions of rows and many years of data.  I'm currently using PowerBI to query the data (ODBC connection), but I don't want to pull everything.  (Recent convert from Crystal.)  Instead, I'm trying to write a clause into my WHERE statement to only query the last three full months of data (excluding the current month.)  So, today being Jan 25,2023 I want to capture Oct 1 2022 - Dec 31 2022.  I would then schedule this so it always pulls the last three months.

My dataset does contain a field that stores the date so I'm trying to write something like the below that I'm able to use to pull previous days.

```
"Table"."OrderDate" >= DATEADD(d,DATEDIFF(d,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-1,0) AND
"Table"."OrderDate" < DATEADD(d,DATEDIFF(d,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),0))
```

Everything so far that I've tried (and found online) gives odd results.  Pulls Nov - Jan and the like.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to pull the last three full months of data. This query uses the `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` functions to calculate the date range for the last three full months.

```
WHERE "Table"."OrderDate" >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 3, 0) AND "Table"."OrderDate" < DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0)
```

Comment: Hi.  Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, it didn't work.  Query pulled from about mid Nov to end of Jan.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the answer. Can you check if it works now?

Comment: Sorry.  It still didn't work.  Pulled the same range of data.  I did more searching online and found other things to try.  I came across a post where someone suggested using something like this.  I tweaked it to meet my needs and it worked.  I'm not sure if it's the best or most effective way to capture this info ... but it works.  

DATEPART(m,"Table"."OrderDate") >= DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -3, getdate())) AND
DATEPART(m,"Table"."OrderDate") <= DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))

Comment: Well, my previous statement is now failing since my last three months are across two years.